# Improving the MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which **filters the row with `replyAutoId=0` and then fetches the most recent record of each `propertyId`.** Now the query takes `0.23225` sec for fetching just `5,435` from `21,369` rows and I want to improve this. All I am asking is, Is there a better way of writing this query ? Any suggestions ?

```
SELECT pc1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM propertyComment WHERE replyAutoId=0) as pc1
                       LEFT JOIN propertyComment as pc2
                            ON pc1.propertyId= pc2.propertyId AND pc1.updatedDate < pc2.updatedDate
                       WHERE pc2.propertyId IS NULL
```

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE propertyComment` Output:

```
CREATE TABLE `propertyComment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `propertyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `agentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `replyAutoId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updatedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `contactDate` date NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `clientStatusId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `adminsId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `propertyId` (`propertyId`),
    KEY `agentId` (`agentId`),
    KEY `status` (`status`),
    KEY `adminsId` (`adminsId`),
    KEY `replyAutoId` (`replyAutoId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=21404 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: how is 0.23225 seconds bad? for a trillion records, that's amazing. for 1 record, that's beyond bad.

Comment: Temporary tables should speed something like this up without too much of a headache...

Comment: It takes that much time for fetching just `5,435` from `21,369` rows

Comment: Should I create temp tables everytime I run this query and drop it after executing them ?

Comment: Would need to better understand your table schema to answer this.  Can you share your SHOW CREATE TABLE output for the table. Also it might be useful for you to explain what you are actually wanting to achieve with this query.

Comment: @Deepak At a minimum you should add an index on `updatedDate` this should help significantly since you are using this as a join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of the nested query.

The following query should give the same result as your original query:

```
SELECT pc1.*
FROM propertyComment AS pc1
LEFT JOIN propertyComment AS pc2
ON pc1.propertyID = pc2.propertyId AND pc1.updatedDate < pc2.updatedDate
WHERE pc1.replyAutoId = 0 AND pc2.propertyID IS NULL
```

Comment: This query will filter the 'replyAutoId = 0` from the resulting query rite ? I want the filtration to happen before joins

Comment: @Deepak  Why?  Are the query results different?

Comment: @Deepak Do you have an example of records that gives different results  for the two queries? In my tests the results are the same.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de40f/1/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pc1.* FROM (SELECT * WHERE replyAutoId=0) as pc1
                       LEFT JOIN (SELECT propertyID, updatedDate from propertyComment order by 1,2) as pc2
                            ON pc1.propertyId= pc2.propertyId AND pc1.updatedDate < pc2.updatedDate
                       WHERE pc2.propertyId IS NULL
```

You also don't have any indexes?

If you did on primary key, you're not joining on it, so why include it?

Why not only select the columns you're interested from B table? This will limit the number of columns you're selecting from table B. Since you're pulling everything from table A where replyAutoID = 0, it wouldn't make much sense to limit the columns there. This should speed it up little.

Comment: This query is taking even more time to execute.

Comment: sometimes the order by's don't use the proper index, can you post an explain statement for both with and without the sub_query on B table?